# Enabling/disabling button

Tags: c#, winforms

I am having trouble getting my 'start' button to show when I select either of the radio boxes.

[image: Screenshot]

Ideally, when one of the boxes is selected, the 'start' button will enable and allow to be clicked.

Here is my code for the form, as I am relatively new to C# I'm not sure if I'm posting all of the code you need, I'll post more if required.

```
    public partial class mainForm : Form
{
    public mainForm() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    }

    private void mainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        title.Font = new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold);
    }

    private void startButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (radioDice.Checked) {
            startButton.Enabled = true; //Activates 'start' button
            whichDiceGameForm GameForm = new whichDiceGameForm(); 
            GameForm.Show(); 
        }
        if (radioCard.Checked) {
            startButton.Enabled = true; //Activates 'start' button
            whichCardGame GameForm = new whichCardGame();
            GameForm.Show(); 
        }

    }
}
```

[Posting for a friend.]

Comment: hint: You have to make use of radio button's selection change events to control the enable and disable states of buttons

Comment: Since one of the two options should always be potentially selected (that is what a RadioButton group is meant for), why not just always have "Start" enabled?

Comment: I know this is a duplicate,but i can't find it, maybe your friend deleted it. As @Rev1.0 said, there is absolutely no point in not having the button always enabled, as one option or the other would always be active

Comment: @Pikoh: He probably handles the initial form state (none of the radio buttons selected) this way. Kristian: if this is the case, just consider setting one of the two RadioButton controls "Checked = true" from the designer or in the mainform constructor (below the InitializeComponent()).

Comment: @Rev1.0 this is a duplicate i already answer yesterday (i guess it was deleted).OP was enabling the button in the CheckedChanged events. And i told him that it was pointless,the same as today

Comment: This is for a friend, not myself, but I'll pass it onto him :)

Comment: @KristianG: Harvesting down-votes for him? ;) Honorable ;)

Comment: It doesn't bother me, too much. I've had this account for around three years, and I generally don't post here. Albeit, I appreciate the answers.

Comment: Found it finally: [Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44114818/579895). But i Can't mark it as duplicate as it has no answers

Comment: Answers have been passed on. Appreciate the help, I should elaborate, not the original OP, nor did I write this [post], understandably that sounds a little unreasonable, check my post history :)

Answer (score 2):

You have placed your enable code in the Button's Click event Handler while you should do it on your checkboxes changed.
Take this code :

```
if (radioDice.Checked) 
{
     startButton.Enabled = true;
}
```

to radioDice checkbox's changed event handler and this one :

```
if (radioCard.Checked) 
{
     startButton.Enabled = true; //Activates 'start' button
}
```

to radioCard checkbox's changed event handler .

Answer (score 1):

Man, seriously?

ANSWER:
You're trying to enable DISABLED button when clicking on that button. You cannot click DISABLED button. What's more - you're duplicating your code.

Button should be always enabled. You only have two choices. Every choice enabled button. So it should be always enabled. No matter the choice. If there is something hidden and button may be disabled, then enable the button in Radio Click event.

**Additional information about your code:**
Now. About code duplication. Look what you're doing in startButton_Click. You have duplicated code.

You can do something like:

```
BaseGameForm f = null;
if(radioDice.Checked)
  f = new DiceGameForm();
else
  if(radioCard.Checked)
      f = new CardGameForm();

f.Show();
```

(BaseGameForm is base form for every game)
But this is not good solution. Better solution is (somewhere in construtor):

```
radioDice.Tag = new DiceGameForm();
radioCard.Tag = new CardGameForm();
```

Then in Start button click you look for checked radio:

```
foreach(Control c in selectGameTypeGroupBox.Controls) //you could do this using LINQ
{
    if((c is RadioButton) && ((RadioButton)c).Checked)
    {
        ((Form)c.Tag).Show();
    }
}
```

But this is still not good solution, because you're creating all game forms at startup and this is stupid.

So the better solution would be to keep game form class name in your radio Tag property and then create object of this class using reflection and Activator.

But this is still not the best solution. But I assume that this is one of your first applications so I won't be telling you now about separating gui from logic. If you want to know more - read on the Internet. Or just ask.

Comment: Will pass this on. Asked for a friend- he's unable to reach the site, at this time. Thankyou :)

Comment: No he needs to disable button on the beginning if he has set for radioButtons checked false by default. In that case he can get case when nothing is chosen and he is starting the game.

Comment: I wrote also about this situation. He has to enable button in common radio click event.